# How to overcome the wastefulness of uniform distributions in a hash function

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, hash-function

Recently on the programming StackOverflow I posted a query about my hash function - I was looking for mistake when there was none. I was alarmed by an empty bucket count of around 36%, as I thought, for an uniform distribution, that that number was erroneously high. Later today I figured it out using the binomial distribution and I realised that the counter-intuitive (similar to birthday problem) 36% “inefficiency” makes perfect sense. Since something cannot surely be more fair than a uniform distribution, how can a real world example of a hashing system reliably and evenly distribute data across **ALL** its buckets - is it even possible? The programmers at StackOverflow tell me that using a modulus of a large prime would help, but mathematically that wouldn’t change the binomial result of 0.3679... - or would it? Please enlighten me or tell me that I’m worrying over nothing and that the 0.367... is unavoidable! Thanks

Note: I am aware that a real world example would have more data points than buckets which would make the number of empty buckets decrease to zero (or would it? I’ve lost confidence in my probability intuitions) - I’m curious about the one-to-one case, where we have near identical numbers in search of a uniform spread

The equations I used to calculate probabilities were: (excuse the mobile phone formatting)

Let N = the number of buckets in the table

Let C = the number of repeat entries or collisions.

The probability of any bucket having C collisions is:

nCr(N, C) * (1/N^C) * (N-1/N)^(N-C) ≈ 0.368,  when C = 0 [empty, wasted bucket], as N tends to infinity.

Comment: > I was alarmed by an empty bucket count of around 36%, as I thought, for an uniform distribution, that that number was erroneously high
You mean that you had 36% empty buckets... for which values of $N$ and how many entries ?

Comment: @leonbloy I tested it with randomly generated string of variable length. I experimented with table sizes of 10,50,100- you name it - and for any given table size I experimented with different entry counts. For example, a system of 50 entries of uniform probability into a table with 50 buckets left me with 18 empty buckets no matter how hard I tried - and I complained about that to StackOverflow until someone showed me it was actually probabilistically correct to have ~36% empty buckets

Comment: I ask as to whether there’s any way that to have a uniformly distributed hash table that doesn’t waste 36% of its table buckets as regardless of entry size or table size my binomial equation is giving me the same answers (as it should)

Comment: If you know ahead of time what the keys will be, you can use _perfect hashing_.

Comment: @MJD is there a dynamic solution to the wastefulness? I find it hard to believe that industry standards such as a python dictionary or some C library or Java implementation of a hashtable would leave 36% of its RAM rotting away... there must be some mathematical trick, no? Or is the binomial issue indefatigable

Comment: This is like complaining that the half of the computer's RAM is wasted because half the bits are zeroes.

Comment: @MJD ok thank you

Comment: @IdioticShrike: nothing is "rotting away". A hash function is designed to generate a seemingly random hash from some input. It's output should behave like a random number generator in that it should fill all bins with equal probability. However, with a small number of samples, like the same as the number of bins, $1/e\approx0.367879$ of the bins will probably be empty. This is just because there will be some multiple hits.

Comment: In fact, the average size of the sample needed to get at least one sample in each bin requires about $N\log(N)+\gamma N$ samples ($\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)).

Comment: With $N=50$, this would mean an average of $225$ samples would be needed to get one sample in every bin. This is not a guarantee of having all bins hit, just the average size of the sample needed to hit all the bins.

Comment: Thank youu o educated one

Comment: @IdioticShrike: Remember that answers and comments were also given on your follow up question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we have $N$ buckets and place $M$ entries in them, with equal probability, the number of elements in each bucket, for large $N,M$, approximately follows ("Poissonization") a Poisson distribution $P_k= e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ with $\lambda=M/N$.

If we denote $X_i=1$ if the bucket $i$ is empty, $0$ otherwise, we have $E[X_i]\approx   e^{-M/N}$ , and if $Z=\sum X_i$ denotes the number of empty buckets we have

$$E[Z] \approx N e^{-M/N}$$

Hence the proportion of empty buckets is approximately $e^{-M/N}$. If $M=N$ we get $0.368$, the $36\%$ you are getting. Notice, however, that this goes to $13.5\%$ for $M=2N$ and so on,

You cannot expect having a better occupation rate for a "universal" hashing function.

Only in special cases (where your key domain has some restrictions) you can do better, see eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

Edit: To prove that the uniform distribution minimizes the expected number of empty buckets you might write

$$E[Z]=\sum_{i=1}^N E[X_i]= \sum_{i=1}^N (1-h_i)^M $$

where $h_i$ is the hashing distribution function. You need only to prove that $h_i=1/N$ attains the minimum, subject to the restrictions $ \sum_{i=1}h_i=1$, $h_i \ge 0$.

Comment: Excellent response thank you. May I ask if it can be formally proven that no better distribution exists? And may I also ask if that means that growing the number of data points diminishes the number of wasted buckets with a Poisson distributed hash, but growing data points with a uniform hash achieves nothing to that extent? Curious how perfectly uniform probability leaves a less uniform outcome

Comment: Why is E[Xi] only approximately equal to e^(-M/N)? For a bucket to be empty, k = 0 so Pk = e ^ (-M/N), so The expected value is, for the discrete Xi, 1 * e ^ (-M/N) + 0 *  (1- e^(-M/N)) so E[Xi] = e^(-M/N)... right? I’ve only briefly glanced at this and I am not at all well versed in these things - where have I gone wrong, does anybody know?

Comment: True, I have not proved that the uniform distribution minimes $E[Z]$, I don't think that would be very difficult.

Comment: "Why is E[Xi] only approximately equal to e^(-M/N)" 
Because of the Poisson approximation. The exact value is $E[X_i] = (1- p_i)^M=(1-1/N)^M$ where $p_i$ is the probability of choosing bucket $i$

Comment: Thank you for your time!