# Expected value of occurrences of a variable under a Poisson distribution

Tags: expected-value, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I asked a question on this forum recently, to which I got a very thorough answer that I didn't properly understand. Link to the original question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993497/how-to-overcome-the-wastefulness-of-uniform-distributions-in-a-hash-function).

The answer stated:

"If we have N buckets and place M entries in them, the number of elements in each buckets, for large $N, m$, approximately follows ("Poissonization") a Poisson distribution $P_k= e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$ with $λ=M/N$.

If we denote $X_i=1$ if the bucket i is empty, 0 otherwise, we have $E[X_i]≈e^{\frac{−M}{N}}$"

How did they derive $E[X_i]≈e^{\frac{−M}{N}}$? I have tried and failed to deduce it myself or find online resources.

Answer (score 1):

The expected value in each bucket is $\frac MN$. Using the Poisson formula, the probability of getting $0$ in a bucket is
$$
e^{-\frac MN}\frac{\left(\frac MN\right)^0}{0!}=e^{-\frac MN}\tag1
$$
A way to visualize this is to note that the probability that placing an entry misses our bucket is $\left(1-\frac1N\right)$. Thus, the probability that all of $M$ entries miss our bucket is
$$
\left(1-\frac1N\right)^M\approx\left(e^{-\frac1N}\right)^M=e^{-\frac MN}\tag2
$$

Comment: Ok - but if their approximation relies on the _binomial_ method of getting e^(-M/N) then what purpose does the poisson distribution even serve in relation to the original post - is this (1-1/N)^M business somehow only applicable in a poisson scenario?

Comment: The Poisson Distribution is a limit of the Binomial Distribution when the probability of success is small but the sample space is large. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3855277) might help to see this relationship.

Comment: So the uniform probability hash is going to tend towards a Poisson distribution as N buckets grows in size?

Comment: You didn't really describe the test of your hash in your previous question, but I see that in [a comment to leonbloy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993497/#comment8241567_3993497) you described it as "a system of 50 entries of uniform probability into a table with 50 buckets left me with 18 empty buckets". Yes; the probability that a given bucket will be left empty is $\left(1-\frac1N\right)^N\sim e^{-1}$.

Comment: The [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties) says that the expected number of buckets left empty will be $N\left(1-\frac1N\right)^N$. Plug in $N=50$ and we get $18.2085$ buckets expected empty. In the limit we will get a fraction of $e^{-1}=0.367879$.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the Poisson approximation then $$E[X_i] = P_0 \approx e^{-M/N} \frac{(M/N)^0}{0!}= e^{-M/N}$$

If you want the binomial route then $$E[X_i] = P(\text{no balls go in that bucket }) = \left(1-\frac1N\right)^M \approx e^{-M/N}$$ for large $M$ and $N$

Comment: Ok - but if their approximation relies on the _binomial_ method of getting e^(-M/N) then what purpose does the poisson distribution even serve in relation to the original post - is this (1-1/N)^M business somehow only applicable in a poisson scenario?

Comment: @IdioticShrike Both routes work and produce the same approximation.  I prefer the binomial version in this particular case but the Poisson version may be easier for approximating the probability for other numbers of balls, and so for some people may be simpler to remember even for empty buckets

Comment: Ah sorry I got confused I didn’t read your answer fully. How is the expected value of P0 only roughly equal to the expression there? Isn’t P0 exactly that expression as that’s what’s detailed by the formula?